# Store multiple of numbers/words into a single database field

Tags: php, mysql

Currently i would simply loop thought the numbers and then add them as a separate row of data.

DB (managedid is a foreign key for ref)

```
  ----------------------
  | managedid | option |
  |-----------|--------|
  |     2     |   3    |
  |     2     |   6    |
  |     2     |   12   |
  |     2     |   54   |
  |     2     |   123  |
  ----------------------
```

But there can be a lot and then to update it i simply would have removed all and re-entered.

But if its possible to do something like:

```
  ------------------------------
  | managedid | option         |
  |-----------|----------------|
  |     2     | 3,6,12,54,123  |
  ------------------------------
```

So not only reducing the of single items within the db table also updating would be simplier.

At the moment i would append say '|' after each number them on output explode them so they again become singular, but was wondering if there was a better way

Comment: The number of people who believe that a single record with a comma separated list is a good idea is really incredible; especially when they then need to do a select where `12` is in the list or similar, and then complain about performance because it can't be indexed on the individual comma-separated values. Don't denormalise because it reduces the number of records in a table, well designed databases can handle billions of records in a table... you're only creating problems for yourself in the future

Comment: i understand you message and always but as i dont need to get any individual value i will always need to get all the values for that one managedid so this is why i wanted to go down the array  concatenate route. thanks for the meesage though is will be good for others to read

Answer (score 3):

Look at the group_concat function in your mySQL manual

Comment: thats the one i could not remember.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the values to a string with `implode()`, but it is worth noting that keeping all the values in a single field makes it very impractical for searching as they can't be reasonably indexed. For example, how would you find all `managedid`s that have selected option `3`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the PHP implode function.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

This will take an array and build a string with a separator of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies but as i will never want to separate any of the values singularly i would always want the total values i wanted to go down this route.

So i went fro my initial thought and looped through the results and added them together separating them via a '|'.

Then using the php function explode to then separate them back out to use within my form.

adding them:

```
     foreach ($options as $k => $opt) { $displayOptions .= $opt . '|'; };
```

getting them

```
     $opts = explode('|',$displayOptions['options']);
```